# How to redirect call to mobile device for Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am creating an app that needs to redirect calls to a mobile device using Twilio.

Using the PHP SDK for Twilio I can make calls to mobile devices using this syntax:

```
$client = new Client($sid,$token);
$call = $client->calls->create(
    "client:voice_test", "client:quick_start",
    array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")
);
```

I can redirect a call to a new URL like this:

```
$call = $client
    ->calls("CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38")
    ->update(
        array(
            "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
            "method" => "POST"
        )
    );
```

Can anyone explain to me using the PHP SDK or really in any language how to redirect a call to a mobile device?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a TwiML Bin.

Configure your Twilio number voice settings for "A CALL COMES IN" with "TwiML" (by default is configured with a webhook URL). To create a new bin, there is a "+" in a red circle sign, to the right of the "TwiML" option. You can only see it after you change from `Webhook` to `TwiML`

The code for the bin for redirect is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>1-555-555-5555</Dial>
</Response>
```

Replace 1-555-555-5555 with your cell number. Save the bin.